# Firmware updates fail to update on Fedora 35 (GNOME Software)

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, upgrade, firmware

(Context: I'm a Linux noob running Fedora 35 on a Thinkpad T14s Gen 2)

Whenever I start up Fedora, GNOME Software shows that I have an update for my T14s Gen 2's firmware from 0.0.9 to 0.1.13. I found a [similar post](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/firmware-updates-dont-install-how-are-they-supposed-to-work/2230/8) made before but the solution isn't apparent. I tried running `fwupdmgr refresh` followed by `fwupdmgr update`, and it looks like the firmware updates, however after the mandatory reboot the update reappears.

In case it matters, my laptop is dual booted with Windows 10 and Fedora 35 encrypted with LUKS. I also notice when booting up my computer there are now two Fedora options that are nearly identical in name.

> Fedora Linux (5.14.10-200.fc35.x86_64) 35 (Workstation Edition)

And

> Fedora Linux (5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64) 35 (Workstation Edition)

I tried booting into the second option to see if that would work, but the problem persists. I have tried posting to other forums but no one has been able to help, so any assistance is very much appreciated.